# Change Textbox backcolor depending on textbox value

Tags: vba

I am having trouble with how to code this properly. I want my textbox to change color if "anything" populates into it when performing another action. I Also do not want it to change at all if nothing is populated into it. So far I have the below.
1.) I can't figure out what to put for the value since it will be different depending on selection. 
2.) how to keep text box the same if nothing populates. It keeps turning to black?

```
Private Sub MailChannel_Change()
```

'Change the color

```
If MailChannel.Text = "" Then
  MailChannel.BackColor = &HC000&
Else
  MailChannel.BackColor = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(153, 255, 255)
    Else
        TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is basically saying if textbox value not blank change it to whatever color that is there otherwise keep it white.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: It may be better to set it to `vbWindowBackground`, just in case the user has another colour set for the background colour in their "Theme".

Comment: @YowE3k I didnt know I could do that! But I guess I might be investigating its properties now

Comment: @user3806255 remember to mark as answered if this works for you.

Comment: @DougCoats I found the reference to it on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227578(v=vs.60).aspx) (look at the table, not at the bit about how to modify the system colours)

Comment: Like wow you can really do some serious customization with that. Still limited for the most part but for vba its very cool