# VBA: Change Font & Back colour of ActiveX Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, colors, fonts, textbox

I have a TextBox just on the worksheet , I barely have tried everything to change Font and Back colours of it , but seems like can change only if TextBox is part of UserForm
Will be very appreciate for answers

Comment: Why do you need to do it with VBA? Can’t you just reformat the shape? Anyway, you can see a related question with answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225947/change-textbox-backcolor-depending-on-textbox-value

Answer (score 1):

To change the font color, let's say to red, try . . .

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

To change the back color, let's say to blue, try . . .

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.BackColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)
```

Change the worksheet name and the RGB colors accordingly.

Comment: @KORDanylo I have edited my post so that it changes the font color and back color for the textbox.

Comment: Instead of `OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object` can you use `Shapes("TextBox1")` - or is that just for Word Object model?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Shapes collection.  However, it would be  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Object.BackColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)`